# Why are the onTouchEvent listeners in my buttonSprite Array returning all the same values?

Tags: android, arrays, while-loop, andengine, touch-event

I've created an array of SpriteButtons with touch listeners as follows:

```
attackCursor.moveToFirst();
while (attackCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {   
    attackButtons[attackButtonsCounter] = new ButtonSprite(0, 0,
        PlayerMenu.getPlayerMenuAttackTR(),
        engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                                     float pTouchAreaLocalX,
                                     float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
                beep.play();
                attackType = Cursor.getInt(0);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
    attackButtonsCounter++;
}
```

when I run it this way I get a error message about touch events. If i replace Cursor.getInt(0) with theAttackButtonsCounter It just makes all the buttons have the data of the last run of the loop. Is there a problem with inserting code into an onAreaTouch() when generated by a loop? I know I don't have the @Override above my touch method. Its not the cause for sure. I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction

Comment: It seems you did move your cursor to next row... => attackCursor.moveToNext(). And did you get an infinite loop?

Comment: In your above code, you only have one attackType variable, so it is overwirted by the while loop, and only keep the value in last loop. If you want every ButtonSprite has its own attackType, you can add `private int attackType;` in your inner ButtonSprite. (the line just before @Override).

Comment: I just saw your post of another question, and realize that you have cursor.moveToNext() in real code, so, ignore my first comment.